# SpringBoot webflux authenticate using query parameter

Tags: spring-boot, authentication, spring-webflux

In Springboot webflux, I can get the current principle using this code

```
Object principal = ReactiveSecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal();
```

If the user is authenticated. But I have a case in which the `JWT` token will be sent as a query paramenter not as the `authorization` header, I know how to  convert the token into `Authentication` object

How i can inject that `Authentication` object into the current `ReactiveSecurityContextHolder`

Comment: Extend the filter that processes the `Authorization` header to also check the query parameter.

Answer (score 1):

You can set your own `Authentication` and take the token from query params as follows:

```java
@Component
public class CustomAuthentication implements ServerSecurityContextRepository {

    private static final String TOKEN_PREFIX = "Bearer ";

    @Autowired
    private ReactiveAuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

    @Override
    public Mono<Void> save(ServerWebExchange serverWebExchange, SecurityContext securityContext) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("No support");
    }

    @Override
    public Mono<SecurityContext> load(ServerWebExchange serverWebExchange) {
        ServerHttpRequest request = serverWebExchange.getRequest();
        String authJwt = request.getQueryParams().getFirst("Authentication");

        if (authJwt != null && authJwt.startsWith(TOKEN_PREFIX)) {
            authJwt = authJwt.replace(TOKEN_PREFIX, "");
            Authentication authentication =
                new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(getPrincipalFromJwt(authJwt), authJwt);
            return this.authenticationManager.authenticate(authentication).map((authentication1 -> new SecurityContextImpl(authentication)));
        }
        return Mono.empty();
    }

    private String getPrincipalFromJwt(String authJwt) {
        return  authJwt;
    }
}
```

This is a simple code block demonstrating how can you achieve your goal. You can improve `getPrincipalFromJwt()` method to return a different object that you would like to set as principal. Or you can use a different implementation of `Authentication` (as opposed to `UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken` in this example) altogether.